# Query data in Google Sheets to get a table that shows day change

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way that I can query some data in Google Sheets so that, instead of getting a table of totals, I get a daily change?

Here is my example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1259GAJ2xzEgTMWJsX5QWsE8RbRXqeXJ0rt1Y_xRd5ls/edit?usp=sharing

I have data that shows a total number of views for each video, and it increments each day. What I want to see instead is the total number of views that each video gets each day. From the data, that would be calculated by taking the total on each day and subtracting the previous day's value.

Complicating things (which I hope is clear in the data) is that new videos will be added, so they'll need to show up alongside the others.

I've been able to easily query and pivot the data, but it still just shows the total views for the video on each day, and I just don't know how to get that same table to show only the change from the previous day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[You may try](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1259GAJ2xzEgTMWJsX5QWsE8RbRXqeXJ0rt1Y_xRd5ls/edit#gid=678090206):*

```js
=map(A3:A,B3:B,C3:C,lambda(a,b,c,if(a="",,let(Λ,filter(A:A,B:B=b),
        {a,b,c-ifna(filter(C:C,B:B=b,A:A=xlookup(a-1,Λ,Λ,,-1)))}))))
```

[image]